# iFrame Resize Based On "Change Source" Button?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've got a weird iFrame situation.  I have a search button that, when clicked, changes the source/URL of the iFrame below it based on the value of its form's values.  That part works nicely, but I can't seem to get the height to adjust properly! The width of the iFrame's content will always be exactly the same, so that's not a problem, but the height isn't changing automatically based on the frame's dynamic content :(  Does anyone know how/if this can be resolved (not fixed... haha)?  Is an iFrame not the right thing to use for something like this?  IE6 support is unfortunately a priority... Thanks for any help you can give, I appreciate it!

Comment: I believe iFrames take static width and height properties (and don't change based on the content). Two solutions come to mind: the first is to do some JavaScript code that access the html node and find the height of it, and then update it to the parent node, and the other one is to use AJAX and place the results in a `<div>`, but I'm not sure if IE6 supports AJAX. **EDIT:** IE6 *does* support AJAX :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-iframe-sizing

This is exactly what I was looking for!  I'm surprised this wasn't easier to find...

Answer (score 0):

try to set iframe height=100%.Example:
, or just write some javascript inside the iframe that resize iframe in base of content change